# passing checkbox data from Controller to handsontable grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, handsontable

I am playing around with a handsontable demo. The load routine gets it's data from the Controller. The Controller routine is

```
  public JsonResult GetCar()
    {
        var jsonData = new[]
                 {
                     new[] {" ","K5GEB", "2023/09/23", "00:30",
                     "40M", "SSB", "LA", "59", "59"},
                     new[] {" ","W5UOT", "2023/03/05", "00:44",
                     "40M", "SSB", "TX", "59", "59"},
                     new[] {" ","W5UOT", "2023/03/06", "00:44",
                     "40M", "SSB", "TX", "59", "59"},
                     new[] {" ","WN0P/P", "2023/02/05", "00:55",
                     "40M", "SSB", "ND", "55", "55"},
                     new[] {" ","NO2CCN/P", "2023/01/05", "01:22",
                     "40M", "SSB", "MI", "59", "59"},
                     new[] {" ","HP3EFS", "2023/10/02", "00:44",
                     "40M", "SSB", "DX", "55", "55"},
                };
       

        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The first column in the Grid table is a Checkbox. Is there a way to make the first element in the Controller be compatible with the Checkbox column in the handsontable.

I tried changing the first element in the Controller from a " " to false or bool. Created an error.